# Determine the used class from GUI application

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, debugging

I know that this question does not make so much sense but I would like to give it a try if somebody has at least hint about it.

I am currently working on a big `GUI` project. For the `GUI` part, the `Swing API` is used.

The project is fairly old and large. Because of these reasons, there are thousands of classes and sub-projects. Sometimes, (especially in bug-fixes) they show me the bug in the GUI and expected me to fix it. However, they are also not sure that on which classes should I focus to fix the bug(s).

Is there any way to identify the used class(es) from `GUI`?

Comment: Well I don't think you could get the right or wrong answers to this question. There are many ways to achieving it. I feel you could be better off googling this subject than asking a question here. Each person will have his or her perspective and opinions and methods.

Comment: @Blip I am highly interested in your way of finding the classes.

Comment: Hi, actually I worked with similar project, in that project also bug fixing was shown on UI and I need to find the class which is responsible for that. For this, I identify any text on that UI and search same text in the complete project code, if it is found in any class, then I changed that text and run it again to verify that the class is same, then I debug that class for the functionality and flow.

Comment: @Sandeep.K I am also using this technique but it is not always giving the best results. Sometimes, a text appears on multiple places (this one is easy to overcome) but sometimes, the responsible project or class is not downloaded (it is added to the project path but not imported via Maven). I think there are better ways, which the other developers use. However, thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an old plugin named swingexplorer can help you I think. With this plugin you can click a swing object and it is showing you the related class names in a tree view. As I said it is an old plugin and apparently it is dead. But you can learn how to use it and download it from [here](http://helpqaspb.com/swing.htm) (see "2. Run application and choose spy tool for this app").

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try it and write here if it works for me.

Comment: I check the tutorial again. It needs some fixes for your situations. At first ignore the 2.8. part. And the other one, at 2.7, just select your main class. By the way I assume that you are using eclipse. I am not sure if there is other versions for other development environments.

Comment: Yes, I am using Eclipse. It is pitty that this project is terminated.